# wp8 app store localization for app name

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, localization, app-store

anyone know how to create localized app name in windows phone app store?
in the app, it's all perfect, the app reads the name from the localized .dll file,
i just followed the msdn article to create language resources:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637522(v=vs.105).aspx

and the following is my app setting in store and MS2012
http://pic.twitter.com/6myhmSe77L

Comment: Do you want random app name depending upon the user's native language ?

Comment: yea, i want a different name for each language, and display it in the app store. cheers

Answer (score 4):

For those who are wondering:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx shows you how to localize the app title. So if you create a DLL for your App it will show a localized title on the phone.

Example: My default language is english but i localize my german title using the     `AppResLib.dll.0407.mui` file. It all works as intended, and my german phone shows the german title. Problem: If you upload the app to the Windows Phone Store, it extracts the localized title from the manifest and xap-file.

**And here's the catch:** Your `WMAppManifest.xml` can only specify the **exact** supported language. For my app, the store would extract the default english title for my german meta data since i specified `de` as the language code. The above document states `de-DE` as the language for german. So make sure your manifest does not contain the generic language code (in your case you probably specified zh) but one that is actually listed.

Answer (score 0):

We use [this helper](http://engine-designs.com/2011/08/17/wp7-appreslib-dll-generator/) to generate AppResLib.dll with localized titles.

It makes app title localization much easier and faster.

There is one more tool to do that: http://patrickgetzmann.wordpress.com/wp7-localize/