# How to localize the App name in the WMAppManifest.xml for Window Phone Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app. The name of the shown in die Windows Phone Store should be localized. For example the name should be "The Game" world wide and "Das Spiel" in German speaking stores, etc.

How can this be done? I have been publishing apps in the iOS App Store. There the Store name can be set in the iTunes Connect (the platform that to upload and manage apps). Different names for different Languages are no problem.

There is no such option in the Windows Phone Dev Center (at least it did not find this option). All information I found are related to the WMAppManifest.xml. But this means that the Store Name and the App Name on the device (tile, App List, etc.) are always the same. Is this right?

I found an article that describes how to localize the name on the phone but there is no information if this also effects the Store name (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Does anyone know how the Store Name can be localized?

Comment: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_solve_problems_localizing_the_app_name

Answer (score 0):

I followed this guide when I needed this on a wp7 app ( didn't use it yet on wp8 ):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pietrobr/archive/2010/11/01/how-to-localize-the-title-in-a-wp7-silverlight-application.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks but this seems to influence only the app name on the device and not in the store.

Answer (score 0):

i just posted an answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276234/wp8-app-store-localization-for-app-name)...

Again the key steps:

1. Localize your app as described on the MS page (Result should be that
   your german phone shows the name "Das Spiel" in the App list)
2. **Make sure you select the Culture referenced in the DLL (`de-DE`) and not the generic culture (`de`) in your `WMAppManifest.xml`**
3. Upload your XAP to the Phone Store. The Store will extract the meta data
   from the file, including the app name. You can edit some other texts then, but not the app title.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will the name in the Store be the same as on the device then? Example: I use the MUI DLL zu localize the app name on the device (tile + app list) to "Das Spiel". Will be "Das Spiel" be the app name in the Store as well? Is it somehow possible to set the Store name independently from the device name? e.g. "Das Spiel" on the Device and "Das Spiel - Super Jump'n Run" in the Store?

Comment: As far as i know it will always be the same. I have not found a way to change the title in the Store-Backend. But the documentation states that you have 2 Names in your DLL AppResLib.dll,-100 and AppResLib.dll,-200 maybe if you change one of them, then change the manifest to use -200 for both and use your long name in the -100 field you could work around it