# Localize Windows Phone app name for Windows Store

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-store

I uploaded multilingual app to Windows Phone Store, I reserve three names for it (one for each languages).
I localized app content and app name (for localized names I used this tutorial `msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff967550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx`) and it works good.

Now, when I looking for my app in Store, I always find it with one name (name for default language).
In some apps, name displayed in Store is depend to phone language (other for en, other for it, ...), and I need to do this.

I find few manuals like these:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh454044.aspx
http://www.win8tutorial.net/resources/localization/
but when I set Display Name in manifest file (WMAppManifest.xml) to: ms-resource:AppName, on apps list I always get an app named ms-resource:AppName.

Does anyone tried localized app name in Windows Store, if so please for help.

Thank for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify this first - the first method (DLL..) you are describing is used for Windows Phone 8.0, the second (ms-resource:AppName..) for 8.1 / WinRT / Windows (Phone) Store apps.

Secondly, I think you are running into this problem with "de" vs "de-de" answered here:
[wp8 app store localization for app name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276234/wp8-app-store-localization-for-app-name)
Apparently if you use generic language code (only "de" instead of "de-de") in your manifest file, the localized app names will not show up on the store.